# Query external database within Joomla using variable in where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am currently writing some queries using Sourcerer within a Joomla 3.7 article to query an external database on the same server, I have the connection OK but for some reason I can't seem to work out how to use a string variable in the Where clause, this is my latest version of the code but I've tried lots!

```
$client = 'test';
$db=JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);
$query=$db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('unit_imei', 'client')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('connections'));
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('client') . ' = ' . $db->quote($client));
$query->where($conditions);
$db->setQuery($query);
$result=$db->loadAssocList();
print_r($result);
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Thanks in advance.

Gordon

Comment: Checked your code and works fine on my localhost server. Are you receive any error ? or it print nothing ?

Comment: Not sure why but when I tried it this morning it worked! Must have been a temporary issue on the server, just wish I had realised that before I spent hours trying to work out what I was doing wrong!